# Falha no adb usando react-native no ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, react-native

Estou com um problema para rodar um app react-native no meu celular.

Com tudo configurado executo

```
react-native start
react-native run-android
```

e aparece o seguinte erro:

> 05:32:56 E/adb: adb server version (32) doesn't match this client (39); killing...

pelo que consegui entender estou com o adb instalado duas vezes no computador, porem nao consigo resolver o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi o problema já, se mais alguem tiver o problema fiz o seguinte

```
sudo find -name adb
```

vi que uma das copias tava no

> ./usr/bin/adb

e outra no

> ./home//Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb

então copiei o da pasta do android para o bin com

```
sudo cp ./home/<usuario>/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb ./usr/bin/
```